# Python multi index merge values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sorting

My issue is I have a list of dictionaries with 3 keys, flag, starttime and ID. I am trying to accomplish a way where in the list gets sorted by the flag first and then the starttime and the ids.My sample list:

```
[{'flag': '143', 'startTime': '2020/02/09/10', 'id': '143'},
 {'flag': '118', 'startTime': '2020/02/08/09', 'id': '118'},
 {'flag': '138', 'startTime': '2020/02/09/05', 'id': '138'},
 {'flag': '144', 'startTime': '2020/02/09/11', 'id': '144'},
 {'flag': '19', 'startTime': '2020/02/04/06', 'id': '19'}]
```

I have tried creating a data frame and then setting index with flag and start time

```
temp = df.set_index(['flag', 'startTime'])
```

and sample temp I got is:

```
flag starttime     id
0   2020/02/03/11   0
    2020/02/03/11   0
1   2020/02/03/12   1
    2020/02/03/12   1
3   2020/02/03/14   3
    ... ... ...
140 2020/02/09/07   140
141 2020/02/09/08   141
142 2020/02/09/09   142
143 2020/02/09/10   143
144 2020/02/09/11   144
```

What I am trying to achieve is, for flag 1 and start time 2020/02/03/03 lets say if there are 3 ids 1,2,3 then my dataframe should look something like:

```
flag sttarttime    id 
   1    2020/02/03/03 1,2,3
   2    2020/02/04/02 9,8,5 etc...
```

Can someone pls help me on this ? Any help on this is greatly appreciated. I have been going mad over this since weeks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe [pandas.DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.groupby(['flag','startTime'])['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

or if you want it as list:

```
df.groupby(['flag','startTime'])['id'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks @loginmind. It worked like a charm. With the list approach, is it possible to restrict the size of list ? Such that if its greater than 2/n it creates a new row?

Comment: Hi @Rahul Goud, I have not checked your question yet, but I can suggest you write a custom function then passed it to apply.

Comment: Also noted that in my answer above, if I used `...['id'].apply(custom_func)` then input to `custom_func` will be a series (because df.groupby(['flag','startTime'])['id'] return SeriesGroupBy)